# Why Curly braces doesn't work instead of parenthesis calling apply method in scala

Tags: scala

AFAIK, in scala, one can choose to use either `curly braces {}` or `parenthesis ()` sending arguments to a method.

```
math.abs{-10}

def fx(x: Int) = x * x
fx{10}

List(1, 3, 5, 7) filter { _ > 5}
```

So, Why this is not applicable to the apply method in object List?

```
List.apply{"A", "B"}   // does not compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method you can pass parameters to it or inside parentheses or without them if it has only one argument. Here `fx {10}` you pass a block of return type Int `{10}` without parentheses. It's equivalent to `fx({10})`.

Here `List(1, 3, 5, 7) filter { _ > 5}` you also pass block  `{ _ > 5}` of return type `Int => Boolean` without parentheses.

In both above cases last block statement is legal expression.

Here `List.apply{"A", "B"}` you pass without parentheses a block `{"A", "B"}` which is equivalent to  `List.apply({"A", "B"})` and `"A", "B"` statement is illegal in Scala.

Comment: Aha, I got it, you mean that, the `{}` is not a replacement for `()`, it is a block. And all cases either I use `{}` or not;  `()` can be omitted for a method if single argument.